# Integration command line software with Java program

Tags: java, design-patterns, integration, processbuilder

I'm integrating open source c program with Java program.

I'd tried to use JNI but it was not appropriate way from what I want to do.

The usage of c program is same as below.

```
program_name argument1 [-a maxSize] [-o maxSizeO] ...... [-P] \
             in.txt in1.dat in2.dat in1.tmp in2.tmp out.txt
```

I could run this program using ProcessBuilder class like this way.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("program_name", 
                                      "argument1", 
                                      "-a", maxSize, 
                                      "-o", maxSizeO........., 
                                      int2.tmp, out.txt);
Process p = pb.start();
```

But There are lots of optional arguments, so it looks like a wrong way to maintain my Java program.

Is there any idea to solve this problem in good way of software design?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` is exactly what you need. I have just written some code skeleton for you. Take it and modify according to your needs.

```
public Process exec(        
        String programName,
        Integer maxSize,
        Integer maxSizeO,
        String[] inFiles,
        String outFile) throws IOException {


    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();

    List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
    cmd.add(programName);
    if (maxSize != null) {
        cmd.add("-a");
        cmd.add("" + maxSize);
    }
    if (maxSizeO != null) {
        cmd.add("-o");
        cmd.add("" + maxSizeO);
    }
    if (inFiles != null) {
        cmd.addAll(Arrays.asList(inFiles));
    }
    if (outFile != null) {
        cmd.add(outFile);
    }

    Process p = pb.start();

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you first define an interface for you functionality. This interface defines methods to set the parameters (mandatory / optional) and to do the actual work. To start with, you then add an implementation which uses `ProcessBuilder` to do the work. This way you can transparently switch to another implementation if you have better solution.